# Locating an Executable and Running the Parent Directory from a Windows Terminal

Tags: command-line, powershell

Originally, I wanted to interactively:

1. Locate the directory of an executable (in the limited case using `where`)
2. Run the parent directory of the executable in Explorer

---

I tried the following in Windows `cmd`:

- It is possible to read the stdout from the cmd `where` command

  ```
  where pip 1> myfile.txt
  ```
- However, what I really wanted was something like

  ```
  where pip | cd.. | explorer
  ```
- `where pip` returns a string with the path of the executable if it's in the system environment's `%PATH%` variable. However, I was unable to figure out how to reach the parent directory based on the string returned from `where`.

---

The solution I found in Power Shell was this:

```
$a = Get-Item((gcm pip.exe).Path); Split-Path -Path $a -Parent | ii
```

Is there a *more compact* solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This …

```
$a = Get-Item((gcm pip.exe).Path); Split-Path -Path $a -Parent | ii
```

.. is literally two independent command. Having them on one line really doe into make this a one-liner, which seems to be your use case.

You can lookup specifically what you can use by using the Get-Member cmdlet.

```
Get-Item((gcm notepad.exe).Path) | Get-Member


   TypeName: System.IO.FileInfo

Name                      MemberType     Definition                                                                                                               
----                      ----------     ----------                                                                                                               
...                                         
PSChildName               NoteProperty   string PSChildName=notepad.exe                                                                                           
PSDrive                   NoteProperty   PSDriveInfo PSDrive=C                                                                                                    
PSIsContainer             NoteProperty   bool PSIsContainer=False                                                                                                 
PSParentPath              NoteProperty   string PSParentPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Windows\system32                                            
PSPath                    NoteProperty   string PSPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe                                      
..                                                                                     
Directory                 Property       System.IO.DirectoryInfo Directory {get;}                                                                                 
DirectoryName             Property       string DirectoryName {get;}                                                                                              
...                                                                                               
FullName                  Property       string FullName {get;}                                                                                                   
...
```

Which of course get you here:

```
(Get-Item((gcm notepad.exe).Path)).Directory
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       12/19/2018   1:33 PM                system32

(Get-Item((gcm notepad.exe).Path)).DirectoryName
C:\Windows\system32

(Get-Item((gcm notepad.exe).Path)).FullName
C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe
```

Thus ...

```
ii (gi((gcm notepad.exe).Path)).FullName
```

Point of note, this is all cool and all for interactive stuff, but best practice in production scripts, aliases and shortname should really be avoided, as it makes script hard to understand and maintain.

Comment: Your answer does not retrieve the parent directory.

Comment: What parent are you after? What I am showing is that the parent of notepad is System32 (which is what your code post does as well, that -Parent), but it appears that you are saying you want to return Windows? The defined PowerShell properties are show via the Get-Member cmdlet. If you want to go up from the full name path, and it being a sub of something else, you have to code for that.